# AS400 apk Tn3270 does not allow the crtpgm to be used F4 key following the command

Tags: ibm-midrange

AS400 " www.pub1.de " free account does not allow the prompting keys. In Mocha Tn3270 and using crtpgm as well as F4 key, message displayed " The File is directed to the Specified Printer " . Please suggest some solution. Wether WWW.pub1.de has not allowed or Mochasoft has not allowed this Function key. Thank You.

Comment: On the site www.pub1.de, I see a link for "Your AS400 help center".  This appears to give you a way to open a ticket to ask a question of the site administrators.  You might have better luck asking this question there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to continue using a TN3270 client emulator, you will need to set your keyboard map. By default, your 3270 PF4 key is currently mapped to the *PRINT function.

To review your options, run this command:

```
===> GO MENU(CMDKBD)
```

This will open a menu of three related keyboard-map commands:

1. Change Keyboard Map
2. Display Keyboard Map
3. Set Keyboard Map

The menu options are for the CHGKBDMAP, DSPKBDMAP and SETKBDMAP commands. Use the 3270 PF1 key for the "Help" function. The DSPKBDMAP command is probably the best one to start with. It will give you a quick view of what your PF keys are currently set as, and you can then begin changing your "map" to work as you prefer.

I don't know how the default map is defined on the server you're using.

As mentioned by @Barry, you might be better off by installing and using a TN5250 client emulator. You can use 3270 (or VT100), but the 5250 protocol is standard.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer for Mocha TN3270 since I've never used it, but [TN5250 (open-source)](http://tn5250.sourceforge.net/) works fine with PUB1.DE.